# How to $match an item from the list

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to display the items, that have specific name brand.
This is how that field looks like:

```
    "brand" : [ 
    [ 
        "Samsung", 
        "Iphone", 
        "Huawei" 
    ]
]
```

Tried that query, but I get 0 results:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: { brand: "Samsung" }}])
```

Any ideas, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model is an **array of arrays** so you have to deal with two dimensions. You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) along with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) first and then use [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) to see if there's any sub-array matching your condition:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $anyElementTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$brand",
                        in: { $in: [ "Samsung", "$$this" ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    },
    {
        $project: {
             _id: 1,
             color: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pceC-8znRF7)

EDIT: use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to display only certain fields

Comment: What would have to be added to display only `id` field and lets say a `color` field of the items that match this condition?